# How to simulate the movement of a bouncing ball with Spritekit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I would like to have a movement looking like this :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the physics engine provided by SpriteKit.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        addPhysicsBoundariesToScene()
        addBall()
    }

    private func addPhysicsBoundariesToScene() {
        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        physicsBody.isDynamic = false
        self.physicsBody = physicsBody
    }

    private func addBall() {
        let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.width / 2)
        physicsBody.restitution = 0.7
        ball.physicsBody = physicsBody
        addChild(ball)
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

### How does it work?

I split the code in 2 methods

### addPhysicsBoundariesToScene()

Create an empty static physic body around the scene.

### addBall()

Create a dynamic physics body for the ball.

If you want to increase the bounce effect increase this value (max 1.0)

```
physicsBody.restitution = 0.7
```

Comment: But how can I have the horizontal movement ?